# python program runtime taking so long/won't end

Tags: python

so i'm doing the dna problem for cs50 wherein i have to count the number of times a STR repeats in a dna sequence. i had an idea on how to solve the problem so i took one of the data and ran my code but the problem is that the program doesn't end and keeps running i think it has been about 10 minutes now from when i started the program and it still like this. here's the code:

```
text="AAGGTAAGTTTAGAATATAAAAGGTGAGTTAAATAGAATAGGTTAAAATTAAAGGAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCAGAAAAGAGTAAATAGTTAAAGAGTAAGATATTGAATTAATGGAAAATATTGTTGGGGAAAGGAGGGATAGAAGG"
length=len(text)
AGAT=0
tmp=0
for i in range(length):
    while text[i]=="A" and text[i+1]=="G" and text[i+2]=="A" and text[i+3]=="T":
        tmp+=1
    if tmp>AGAT:
        AGAT=tmp
    else:
        AGAT=AGAT
print("done")
```

Comment: Your while loop only changes `tmp` which has no bearing on the loop condition, so it'll either run zero times or forever.

Comment: there is an infinite loop in `while`. when there is an `AGAT` in the string, continuously iterates there

Comment: On a sidenote, `AGAT=AGAT` is not necessary. It's ok without any `else` statement

Comment: You can use a debugger to go through it line-by-line, or add a `print("found AGAT")` inside the while loop. You'll see that it gets stuck in the while loop. You need to either `continue` to the next `i` or `break` out of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments there is an infinite loop in your while loop, you could just remove it and choose to use a sliding window technique where you go over the text looking at neighbouring slices of 4 adjacent characters at a time:

```
text = "AAGGTAAGTTTAGAATATAAAAGGTGAGTTAAATAGAATAGGTTAAAATTAAAGGAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCAGAAAAGAGTAAATAGTTAAAGAGTAAGATATTGAATTAATGGAAAATATTGTTGGGGAAAGGAGGGATAGAAGG"
search_seq = "AGAT"
count = 0
for i in range(len(text) - len(search_seq) + 1):
    if text[i:i+len(search_seq)] == search_seq:
        count += 1
print(f"Sequence {search_seq} found {count} times")
```

**Output:**

```
Sequence AGAT found 5 times
```

Comment: The For loop goes from `0`, to `length` - `length of search seq` + `1` since the range stop (https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#ranges) is exclusive. Then for each index, `i` we look at the 4 characters group starting at that `i` to see `if` it equals the search sequence, and increment the counter if it does.

Comment: thanks so much for your reply, i now understand the concept

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a weird way to solve your problem but i wanted to do something a bit different...
Try this:

```
agat_string="AAGGTAAGTTTAGAATATAAAAGGTGAGTTAAATAGAATAGGTTAAAATTAAAGGAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCAGAAAAGAGTAAATAGTTAAAGAGTAAGATATTGAATTAATGGAAAATATTGTTGGGGAAAGGAGGGATAGAAGG"
agat_list=[AGAT for AGAT in range(len(agat_string)) if agat_string.find("AGAT", AGAT) == AGAT] #finds the indices of "AGAT" ;-)
print(len(agat_list))
```

The output:

```
5
```

Also, as someone said, tmp has nothing to do with the while condition. It just throws you in an infinite loop....